# mysql Extract json element from array

Tags: mysql, json

I need to extract JSON element by index e.g.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"featureId":"a","read":1,"write":1,"delete":1},{"featureId":"2","read":1,"write":0,"delete":1}]', '$[0].*');
```

But it just extracts the values I want extracted part to be like this:

```
{
    "featureId": "a",
    "read": 1,
    "write": 1,
    "delete": 1
}
```

Comment: You can use `select JSON_OBJECT('[{"featureId":"a","read":1,"write":1,"delete":1},{"featureId":"2","read":1,"write":0,"delete":1}]', '$[0].*');`

Comment: it does not work. It returns complete json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('
  [
    {"featureId":"a","read":1,"write":1,"delete":1},
    {"featureId":"2","read":1,"write":0,"delete":1}
  ]
', '$[0]');
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b1iLxFmsBHF3fArstWiTuQ/0).