# MySQL Extract JSON from select query with two relational tables

Tags: mysql, json, inner-join

Hi I am working on a Select Query that combines two relational tables with customer information. The field called 'options' contains a lot of JSON information.

I found a similar article however I am unable to make it work within the context of the existing query and the server gives an error message function 'JSON_EXTRACT' does not exist. Upon further review we discovered that the server itself does not have the JSON_EXTRACT function.

Is it possible to simply use % % between two strings?

i.e.  select  between   {"TransactionID":"       and    "}

just interpreting the JSON ourselves rather than relying on a server function.

Here is the query

```
select u.Email, u.Name, up.Type, up.Name, up.Price, up.options from users_packages 
inner join users u on up.UserID = u.id
```

The options field reveals this value for example:

{"TransactionID":"4G631007P6080114Y39840"}

I'm looking for a query that will give me only the value i.e. '4G631007P6080114Y39840' and extract the JSON of the TransactionID.   Note, some of the other json elements may be there other than TransactionID

Thanks!

See 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063684/mysql-extract-json-element-from-array](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063684/mysql-extract-json-element-from-array)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running (`select version()`)?

Comment: The MYSQL VERSION IS : 5.5.56-MariaDB

Comment: JSON support was added in MySQL 5.7, so json functions such as `JSON_EXTRACT()` are not available in 5.5. If you want to work with JSON, you should really consider upgrading (besides, 5.5 is a *really* old version, which is out of support).

Comment: I understand. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve upgrading the MySQL version on that server? perhaps thru strings?

Comment: We upgraded to Maria DB 10.1 the JSON_EXTRACT function does not exist there either.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this 
JSON_EXTRACT(yourJSON, "$.fieldname")

```
select u.Email, u.Name, up.Type, up.Name, up.Price, JSON_EXTRACT(up.options, "$.TransactionID") from users_packages inner join users u on up.UserID = u.id
```

here you have how json_extract works
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html